# How to extract / use output from SAS proc

Tags: r, sas

Very familiar with what I am trying to do in R. But I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how to manipulate the output of a SAS proc.

The R code I ran is

```
mylogit <-glm(tvsitcom ~ gender+age,data=student,family = "binomial")
odds_ratio <-exp(coef(mylogit))
```

The SAS code I am attempting to do the same however I am cannot figure out how to take e^(Parameters) for each of the Parameters in the output. Do I need to use a seperate PROC for this?

```
proc reg data=perm.college;
    model tvsitcom=age gender;
    ods output ParameterEstimates;
    run;
```

Based on the answer below I have update the question with the answer:

```
proc reg data=perm.college;
    model tvsitcom=age gender;
    ods output ParameterEstimates=param;
    run;

data or;
    set param;
    odds_ratio=exp(Estimate);
run;
```

Comment: Does `model tvsitcom=age gender /expb;` do it?

Comment: not an option in proc reg

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using PROC LOGISTIC or GLM which are more similar to the R glm command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example for you:

```
proc reg data=SASHELP.CARS;
    model Horsepower=EngineSize Cylinders MPG_City;
    ods output ParameterEstimates=data1;
run;

data want;
    set data1;
    odds_ratio=exp(Estimate);
run;
```